# Data disappear from from in php after page refresh

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Data disappear when i reload/refresh the form.

**My query for getting data..**

```
 public function view_detail()
    {
        $qry=$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM student_detail WHERE Student_Cnic=:search OR Student_Name=:search");
        $qry->bindParam(':search',$this->stsearch);

        $qry->execute();
        return $qry;
    }
```

**The form from where i am sending data**

```
 <form action="view.php" method="post" id="view_form">
                            <br>
                            <label for="">View By Name or CNIC</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stu-view" id="stu-view" placeholder="Student Name or CNIC"><br>

                            <input type="submit" name="view-detail" id="view-detail" class="btn btn-success" value="Enroll"><br>
                        </form>
```

**The form where i am populating data**

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'config.php';
include 'classes.php';
$database=new Database();
$db=$database->getConnection();
$gtstu=new stu_sys($db);

if(isset($_POST['stu-view']))
{
$_SESSION['stusearch'] = $_POST['stu-view'];
if(isset($_SESSION['stusearch'])){
    $gtstu->stsearch = $_SESSION['stusearch'];
}
}
$fth = $gtstu->view_detail();


?>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8" style="margin-top: 10%;">

            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Cnic</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>View Detail</th>
                <?php while($row = $fth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row->Student_Image; ?>" alt=""/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Student_Name ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Student_Cnic ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Deprt ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#">View More Detail</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
            <a href="dashboard.php" class="btn btn-primary">Back TO Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>

    </div>

</div>











<?php
include 'footer.php'
?>
```

i don't know why the form goes empty, mean when i reload the page the data wiped..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you submit the form the data is submit on php server and when you refresh the page the data loses. You should use session for this purpose.

Comment: The form where the data is being populated will never work for one simple reason: You're not including `session_start();` at the top of your code. So on page refresh, the sessions are destroyed.

Comment: thanks @icecub i forgot to add the session on page.

Comment: You're welcome :) Such trivial mistakes are easily made, haha

Answer (score 1):

*The form where the data is being populated will never work for one simple reason: You're not including session_start(); at the top of your code. So on page refresh, the sessions are destroyed.*

**My mistake:**  I forgot to add `session_start()` on top of page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['stu-view']))
{
   $_SESSION['stusearch'] = $_POST['stu-view'];     
}

// Move this out
if(isset($_SESSION['stusearch'])){
   $gtstu->stsearch = $_SESSION['stusearch'];
    }
```

I would assume  that you are not resending the data in the form. So you are not getting the data from session because you only look at session if the data is sent,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the form you are "sending data from", you should add a value attribute to the textbox (stu-view) and populate it with the submitted search value i.e. add:

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['stusearch']; ?>"
```