# PHP pages disappear after post method

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My PHP pages go nearly blank when I run a post method with a form. I want to know whether it's a problem with the Google Cloud platform or a problem with the way I loaded the application onto the Google Cloud Platform. Here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php

env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: .

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.(html|png|jpg|js|css))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(html|png|jpg|js|css)$

- url: /.*
  script: auto

entrypoint:
  serve handler.php

env_variables:
  CLOUDSQL_USER: root
  CLOUDSQL_DB: COSGymPatronData
  CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: ************
  CLOUDSQL_DSN: /cloudsql/cosgym:us-central1:cosgympatrondata
```

Here is my handler.php:

```
<?php
    ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);
    switch(@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
        case '/':
            require 'index.php';
        case '/index':
            require 'index.php';
        case '/index.php':
            require 'index.php';
        case '/result_contact.php':
            require 'result_contact.php';
        case '/checkout.php':
            require 'checkout.php';  
        case '/loginAction.php': 
            require 'loginAction.php';
        case 'signinAction.php':
            require 'signinAction.php';
    }
?>
```

And here is my database.php page:

```
<?php

    function prepare_string($dbc, $string) {
        $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($string));
        return $string;
    }

    define('DB_USER', get_env('CLOUDSQL_USER'));
    define('DB_PASSWORD', get_env('CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD'));
    define('DB_HOST', get_env('CLOUDSQL_DSN'));
    define('DB_NAME', get_env('CLOUDSQL_DB'));

    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
?>
```

And finally, here's an example of the php that runs on the action page for the previous form:

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

$errors=[];

if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = NULL;
    $errors[] = "<p>We need your name </p>";
}


if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] =  "<p>Your email is incorrect '$email' </p>";
        $email = NULL;        
    }
}else{
    $errors[] =  "<p>We need your email </p>";
    $email = NULL;        
}


if(!empty($_POST['subject'])) {
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
} else {
    $subject = NULL;
    $errors[] = "<p>We need your subject </p>";
}


if(!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
} else {
    $message = NULL;
    $errors[] = "<p>We need your message </p>";
}

$name_clean = prepare_string($dbc, $name);
$email_clean = prepare_string($dbc, $email);
$subject_clean = prepare_string($dbc, $subject);
$message_clean = prepare_string($dbc, $message);

$q = "INSERT INTO Contact(name, email, subject, message) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
    $stmt,
    'ssss',
    $name_clean,
    $email_clean,
    $subject_clean,
    $message_clean
);

$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (!$result)
{
    $errors[]="<p>Error Access DB</p>";
}

if(count($errors)==0) {

    echo "<p>Welcome to COS GYM Our managers will contact you</p>";

}else
{
    foreach($errors as $err) 
    {
        echo $err;
    }
}
?>
```

I should note that I'm being charged on the free credits for what's running onto the CloudSQL and App Engine, and that data looks like it's going into the database, so it seems like the code on the results page is working. Help figuring this out would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, is the issued resolved?

Comment: Not yet. I still have the issue.

Comment: is your code working on local environment? If you have not tried yet, then I recommend you to try it before loading the application on Google Cloud Platform. Can you also provide your html code?

Comment: It's working locally. Here's the code that I am using for the example contact page:

Comment: https://github.com/CShingiro/Group2Project/blob/main/result_contact.php

Comment: Here's the form that loads to it: https://github.com/CShingiro/Group2Project/blob/main/contact.html

Comment: Have you included session_start() at the top of your code, as mentioned in the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623675/15774177).

Comment: Wait, why would I need to do that for using $_POST[]? Isn't that only necessary for $_SESSION[]?

Comment: Hi @SRGWaterloo, if you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark on the left side under the vote arrows and upvoting it. I'd really appreciate it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of AppEngine, when looking at the app.yaml, is not correctly defined. Let's take it apart one element at a time.
[runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref) - this should be explicit, i.e. php73 or php74 or php55
runtime_config: this is incorrect and not part of this context as it belongs with the [python runtime options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) in AppEngine

The handlers seem alright, but next we have;
entrypoint:

This means the handler.php file determines where to send requests.

From this file we see '/result_contact.php' requires 'result_contact.php', so the 'contact.html' would be the source at lines 42 through 52 for the POST request in question.

As there are no elements in the code that would cause the display to go blank (explicitly), this is PHP driven, most likely to do with the code.
As the PHP only adds an echo in result_contact.php through lines 109 or 115, you should consider returning these values.